# Extracting the index of key frames from a video using ffmpeg

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg

Can you tell me the command for extracting the index of key frames from a video using `ffmpeg` in Windows. I tried

```
ffprobe -select_streams v -show_frames \
  -show_entries frame=pict_type \
  -of csv bbb480.avi \
  | grep -n I | cut -d ':' -f 1 > frame_indices.txt
```

but this error is displayed:

> 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, grep isn't available unless you install a package such as a port of [coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).

Anyway, you can run

```
ffprobe in.mp4 -select_streams v -show_entries frame=key_frame,pkt_pts_time -of csv=nk=1:p=0 | findstr "1,"
```

Comment: Thank you sir for answering the question .But by using above command I am getting only key frame time instant not keyframe index.Can you please suggest the command for keyframe index.              Thank you sir.